Is there a way to reduce the size of .exe created by Pyinstaller or Nuitka?
The size of the .exe of my software is too large (2,5GB) i would like to reduce it. Here is my code for analysis:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, ttk
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM
import srt
import os
from huggingface_hub import login, HfApi, cached_download
import logging
import keyring
import re
import sys
import subprocess
import importlib
from threading import Thread

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

translation_cancelled = False


class TokenInvalidoError(Exception):
    pass


class ErroDeTraducao(Exception):
    pass


def download_pytorch():
    try:
        python_exe = sys.executable
        pip_command = [python_exe, "-m", "pip", "install", "--user", "torch", "torchvision", "torchaudio",
                       "--extra-index-url", "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117"]

        result = subprocess.run(pip_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

        if result.returncode == 0:
            user_site = subprocess.check_output([python_exe, "-m", "site", "--user-site"]).decode().strip()
            sys.path.append(user_site)
            return True
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Erro", f"Falha ao instalar PyTorch: {result.stderr}")
            return False
    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Erro", f"Falha ao instalar PyTorch: {str(e)}")
        return False


def import_pytorch_dynamically():
    if 'torch' in sys.modules:
        return importlib.import_module('torch')

    if download_pytorch():
        sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "pytorch_temp"))  # Diretório temporário
        torch = importlib.import_module("torch")
        return torch
    return None


def clean_text(text):
    text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text)
    text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', text)
    return text


def save_token(token):
    keyring.set_password('huggingface', 'user', token)


def load_token():
    return keyring.get_password('huggingface', 'user')


def validate_token(token):
    api = HfApi()
    try:
        api.whoami(token)
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False


def download_model_from_hub(token):
    try:
        api = HfApi()
        model_name = "facebook/nllb-200-3.3B"
        model_dir = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), ".cache", "huggingface", "hub",
                                 "models--facebook--nllb-200-3.3B")
        if not os.path.exists(model_dir):
            login(token)

            model_path = cached_download(model_name, cache_dir=model_dir)
            messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Model downloaded successfully.")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Model Exists", "The model is already downloaded.")
    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Failed to download the model: {str(e)}")


def get_translator(src_lang, tgt_lang):
    torch = import_pytorch_dynamically()
    if not torch:
        return None, None, None, None

    try:
        model_name = "facebook/nllb-200-3.3B"
        tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
        model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_name)

        device = 'cpu'
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            device = 'cuda'
        elif torch.backends.mps.is_available():
            device = 'mps'
        elif torch.backends.rocm.is_available():
            device = 'rocm'
        else:
            device = 'cpu'
        model.to(device)

        def translator(texts):
            try:
                texts = [clean_text(text) for text in texts]
                tokenizer.src_lang = src_lang
                encoded_texts = tokenizer(texts, return_tensors="pt", padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=512)
                if device != 'cpu':
                    encoded_texts = {k: v.to(device) for k, v in encoded_texts.items()}
                generated_tokens = model.generate(
                    **encoded_texts,
                    forced_bos_token_id=tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tgt_lang),
                    max_length=512,
                    num_beams=4,
                    no_repeat_ngram_size=2
                )
                return generated_tokens
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error("Error generating tokens: ", exc_info=True)
                return None

        return translator, tokenizer, model, device
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Error loading the model: ", exc_info=True)
        return None, None, None, None


def translate_texts(texts, translator, tokenizer, device):
    try:
        logging.info(f"Translating batch of size {len(texts)}")
        translated = translator(texts)
        if translated is None:
            raise ErroDeTraducao("Translation failed")
        result = tokenizer.batch_decode(translated, skip_special_tokens=True)
        return result
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Error in translation: ", exc_info=True)
        return texts


def chunks(lst, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]


def translate_srt(input_file, src_lang, tgt_lang, progress_callback):
    global translation_cancelled
    translation_cancelled = False
    translator, tokenizer, model, device = get_translator(src_lang, tgt_lang)
    if translator is None or tokenizer is None or model is None or device is None:
        return None

    try:
        with open(input_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            subs = list(srt.parse(f.read()))

        total_subs = len(subs)
        batch_size = 5
        translated_subs = []

        for i, batch in enumerate(chunks(subs, batch_size)):
            if translation_cancelled:
                logging.info("Translation cancelled")
                return None
            texts = [sub.content for sub in batch]
            translated_texts = translate_texts(texts, translator, tokenizer, device)
            for sub, translated_text in zip(batch, translated_texts):
                sub.content = translated_text
                translated_subs.append(sub)
            progress_callback((i + 1) * batch_size, total_subs)
            logging.info(f"Processed batch {i + 1}/{(total_subs + batch_size - 1) // batch_size}")

        output_file = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Downloads', f"translated_{os.path.basename(input_file)}")
        with open(output_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(srt.compose(translated_subs))
        return output_file
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Error processing SRT file: ", exc_info=True)
        return None


def upload_file():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("SRT files", "*.srt")])
    if file_path:
        file_label.config(text=os.path.basename(file_path))
        file_label.file_path = file_path


def process_translation():
    if not hasattr(file_label, 'file_path'):
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please select an SRT file.")
        return

    src_language = src_language_entry.get()
    tgt_language = tgt_language_entry.get()
    token = token_entry.get()
    if not src_language or not tgt_language:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter source and target languages.")
        return

    if not token:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter the Hugging Face API token.")
        return

    if not validate_token(token):
        raise TokenInvalidoError("Token inválido ou expirado")

    save_token(token)
    login(token)

    progress_bar['value'] = 0
    progress_bar.update()

    def run_translation():
        try:
            download_model_from_hub(token)
            output_file = translate_srt(file_label.file_path, src_language, tgt_language, update_progress)
            if output_file:
                root.after(0, lambda: messagebox.showinfo("Success", f"Translated file saved at: {output_file}"))
        except Exception as e:
            root.after(0, lambda: messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Error translating the file: {e}"))

    thread = Thread(target=run_translation)
    thread.start()


def start_translation():
    if import_pytorch_dynamically():
        process_translation()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Translation could not be initiated without PyTorch.")


def update_progress(current, total):
    progress_bar['value'] = (current / total) * 100
    root.update_idletasks()


def cancel_translation():
    global translation_cancelled
    translation_cancelled = True


def toggle_token_visibility():
    if token_entry.cget('show') == '*':
        token_entry.config(show='')
        show_hide_button.config(text='Hide')
    else:
        token_entry.config(show='*')
        show_hide_button.config(text='Show')


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("SRT Translator")

frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding="10")
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.W, tk.E, tk.N, tk.S))

ttk.Label(frame, text="SRT File:").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)
file_label = ttk.Label(frame, text="No file selected")
file_label.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

upload_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Upload SRT File", command=upload_file)
upload_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

ttk.Label(frame, text="Source Language:").grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)
src_language_entry = ttk.Entry(frame)
src_language_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

ttk.Label(frame, text="Target Language:").grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)
tgt_language_entry = ttk.Entry(frame)
tgt_language_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

ttk.Label(frame, text="Hugging Face Token:").grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)
token_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, show='*')
token_entry.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

show_hide_button = ttk.Button(frame, text='Show', command=toggle_token_visibility)
show_hide_button.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

start_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Start Translation", command=start_translation)
start_button.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=10)

progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='determinate')
progress_bar.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=5)

cancel_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Cancel", command=cancel_translation)
cancel_button.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=10)

root.mainloop()

I tried to use Nuitka, to edit pyinstaller configs, when I exclude the modules from the installer it becomes smaller but i need the modules, maybe if they are downloaded on demand in the user system using requirements or something would be better.

Those are some pretty heavy libraries you're using so you're not gonna get it super low, but the most critical tip for compiling is to always always always create a virtual environment (python.exe -m venv venv, then venv\scripts\activate on Windows) and install exactly the packages you need and nothing else (don't forget to enter the virtual environment before compiling each time).
Compiling with PyInstaller 6.9.0 on Python 3.12.4, I get the following results from a clean virtual environment:
With --onefile:    149mb
Without --onefile: 424mb (2,776 files)

Those are pretty big, but they're an absolute miracle compared to just a few years ago when a PyInstaller executable for a library-less command line program would be like 40mb.

Apart from the virtual environment, you can also use UPX https://github.com/upx/upx for pyinstaller to reduce the size of exe. Nuitka uses zstandard package to reduce the size when you try to build your project into one exe file.

hey can you show me how you did this? because I'm already using a virtuaenv but the folder is 4gb , i dont know if you got to run it but I will try a fresh clean virtual env thanks a lot for the answer

there is any way to make these libraries download when the user run the .exe in his computer?

@MaloneFreak Actually, technically yes, you can do that. Even in a compiled executable, a library's files are only loaded when you import it. You can create a function that checks if a library is already imported (if 'torch' in sys.modules: <- use the module's name as a string), and downloads the files from somewhere just before importing if needed. torch is a good example, as it doesn't appear to be used until the user manually clicks a button, which would be a good spot to prompt/alert the user that you're going to download the library first (assuming you don't download them on launch).

Thanks a lot bro but I think im incompetent for that, I tried everything but when i click start translation the gui bugs and nothing happens I will share with you the link for the github of  my project link feel free to make pull requests if you want

I updated the question with the last code that I did thanks anyway :D
